# kartik-v/yii2-grid need simple example of usage

Tags: php, yii2

I want use "kartik-v/yii2-grid" lib for rendering grid.
but I can't understand how it use.
In manual its example a simple usage a lib but not explains what vars must contain
    
    `use kartik\grid\GridView;
    echo GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider'=> $dataProvider, // What is it $dataProvider ?
    'filterModel' => $searchModel, // what is it $searchModel ?
    'columns' => $gridColumns, // what is it $gridColumns ?
    'responsive'=>true,
    'hover'=>true
    ]);`

Comment: I'd suggest that you take the time to familiarise yourself with the basic grid view widget. It will answer many of your questions. The manual is here; http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-output-data-widgets.html#gridview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am new to Yii2 as well and took me some time to understand the documentation.

First of all in the kartik-v/yii2-grid you have 2 button links that show you the main data you are missing.

parameters: http://demos.krajee.com/grid

Demo: http://demos.krajee.com/grid-demo

In the demo links you can play with the grid and then hit:

[image: grid doc]

In the configure you have the main grid data code and in the grid columns setup you will find the columns configuration.

You can see a complete sample with few grids in the project i am working on that it is base in the yii2 advanced application and using kartic extensions:

[project using kartik grid](https://github.com/open-ecommerce/oe-dropin)

In frontend/customers/index you will find a complex one that use expand, datepics and functions to pull other tables values.

in frontend/doctor/index.php you can see a very simple that use a single model.

I think the key is to create a simple model control and curd and analyse the model and the modelsearch that it is use to create the datasets.

good luck !!

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a simple example to start with using Gii.

1. Start by creating a model in Gii from a database table. (auto-generated)
2. Create the CRUD in Gii for that model (auto-generated)
3. The code you see above will be autogenerated for you using the default Yii2 Grid.  In the view change:

   `use yii\grid\GridView;`
   to:
   `use kartik\grid\GridView;`

Kartik Gridview extends the Yii gridview.  So it will work just fine and you can take it from there by adding more attributes per the Kartik documentation.